# OSMDroid and shapefile (.dbf, .shp, shx) display

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am currently working with OSMDroid and try to display offline map using vector data that represented as .dbf, .shp, .shx files. I googled a lot but still can't find solution how to do this using OSMDroid. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMDroid is designed to handle bitmap tiles, not vector maps.

Have a look to [Mapsforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/), it could be more appropriate to your need.

You will have to convert your shapefile to Mapsforge. An entry point [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94646/how-to-convert-from-shp-to-map-for-mapsforge).